# Can I put a restaurant chaffing pan on an induction burner?

Tags: stainless-steel

I have full size chafing pans, about 6" deep, 22' long, 14" wide. This is the standard restaurant type and I believe made of stainless steel.

I want to can some large amounts of broth but using my largest pot would take forever. 2 of these chaffing pans could hold a lot of cans.

Could I put these chaffing pans directly on an induction range? I have 2 long burners.

I boil maple syrup in these things on a huge fire so I reckon they can take the heat.

Comment: I don’t know about using these pans on an induction burner, but canning stock requires a pressure canner to be made safely.

Comment: @DebbieM. This is often true but not always.

Answer (score 2):

It might work if they are the right kind of stainless steel, however I suspect you could run into issues because the metal is pretty thin:

1. Thin metal may not have enough mass for the magnetic field to interact with, so the dishes may not be detected, or the amount of energy may not be enough to heat the pan. I had a situation where a thin pan just wouldn't heat up enough to cook with
2. The metal could warp. Stainless isn't actually that great a conductor of heat, so as the pans are really large the temperature differential between hot (presuming they heat properly) and cool could be very significant
3. The pans may not heat throughout. Stainless steel isn't a great conductor, so if the dish is much bigger than the burner you'll have hot spots and cool spots. That may or may not be an issue depending on how you want to cook
4. You'll want to be careful to make sure the pan doesn't cover the sensitive electronics, as heat can fry the circuit board and total your cooktop. As the dish is very big you'll need to keep that in mind

Bottom line is you won't lose anything by testing to see if the pan is detected, if it is you can experiment with it, just don't go for max heat right away.